# python styleguide pep 8 . multiline multicolumn dict

Tags: python, coding-style, pep8

Hi when i have a multidimensional dictionary that i want to use, and i access it with variables with some longer names i run into some +80 char lines. How can i shorten this in accordance to pep8.

For example:

```
myvalue = mydict[application_module][chapter][paragraph][line][character][some_other_value]
```

**question**: How can i shorten/multiline this without renaming my variables?

I know i can do:

```
myvalue = mydict[application_module] \
                [chapter] \
                [paragraph] \
                [line] \
                [some_other_value]
```

Is using the \ for muliline the only solution?

Comment: Or use parens `()` around the expression then you can break it across lines without a continuation character - something I'm finding myself do a lot working in pyspark.

Comment: Tnx, that was indeed the solution i was looking for. I just wanted a simple solution to not have to include a \ .... I find them ugly ;) , but still adhere to the style guides.  I'll have to make up my mind now which i find less appalling ;) haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in order to refuse of raising a syntax error you need to escape the new lines. But as another alternative approach you can use a recursive function to get the value from a nested dictionary:

```
>>> d = {1: {2: {3: {4: {5: 'a'}}}}}
>>> def get_item(d,*keys):
...    for i,j in enumerate(keys):
...        item = d[j]
...        if isinstance(item, dict):
...           return get_item(item,*keys[i+1:])
...        return item
```

Or with a generator expression within `next`:

```
>>> def get_item(d,*keys):
...   return next(get_item(d[j],*keys[i+1:]) if isinstance(d[j],dict) else d[j] for i,j in enumerate(keys))
... 
>>> print get_item(d,1,2,3,4,5)
a
```

or as a more pythonic way you can pass an iterator of keys to your function :

```
def get_item(d,keys):
    try:            
        item = d[next(keys)]
    except KeyError:
        raise Exception("There is a mismatch within your keys")
    if isinstance(item, dict):
       return get_item(item,keys)
    return item
```

Comment: The above solution was simple enough, but otoh this seems like a neat thing too. Just make one retrieval function which i can multiline more elegantly than with \ or () ... tnx